# What is the cost of entry/membership in the Android Marketplace?

Tags: android, google-play

I don't recall this information being immediately accessible.

Last month I read

> In Google's Android application market, no pre-approval is required, though registration is 
>   needed for distribution. Developers need to register as developers (cost $25/year) with a 
>   Google account and sell their products through a published site. NonDfree applications can be 
>   sold after configuring the bank information.

source: bada_development_guide_for_android_developer_modified_final.pdf pp5, date 10/7/2011

while bada was free. I suspect I was reading old information, bada cost £1 for seller registration last time I checked. But I don't think Android ever cost £25/year and this was just Samsung pushing their own alternative OS.

Comment: John this is an off topic question for SO. As response check this: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113468

Comment: Ok, fair play. No need to vote it down, it has been answered. Just trying to dispel some of the untruths that abound on the interweb.

Comment: I didn't vote down. One up vote from me to balance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

App publisher registration on Google Play (formerly Android Market) has always been a $25, one time fee-  Whatever literature you were reading was incorrect.

From the [Developer Registration support page](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113468):

> You must register to be able to distribute your products through Google Play. There is a one time $25 registration fee. We charge this fee to encourage higher quality products on Google Play (e.g. less spammy products).

Comment: Also deters fraudsters and scam artists. Good to know your currency is accepted. No doubt expect to be shafted if converting currency.

Comment: There is a $25 USD one-time registration fee that you can pay with the following credit or debit cards:

MasterCard
Visa
American Express
Discover (U.S. only)
Visa Electron (Outside of the U.S. only)
Note: The types of cards accepted may vary by location. 
chekc this link for more detail     https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=en